# Cannot find main class SolrCLI when running bin/solr -e cloud

Tags: solr4, solrcloud

I want to compile solr from the main trunk and run it.
I did the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr.git
cd lucene-solr/solr
ant dist
bin/solr -e cloud
```

This creates the relevant solr nodes but fails to create a collection with the following error:

```
$ bin/solr -e cloud

Welcome to the SolrCloud example!


This interactive session will help you launch a SolrCloud cluster on your local workstation.

To begin, how many Solr nodes would you like to run in your local cluster? (specify 1-4 nodes) [2] 
Ok, let's start up 2 Solr nodes for your example SolrCloud cluster.

Please enter the port for node1 [8983] 
8983
Please enter the port for node2 [7574] 
7574

Starting up SolrCloud node1 on port 8983 using command:

solr start -cloud -s example/cloud/node1/solr -p 8983   


Waiting to see Solr listening on port 8983 [|]  
Started Solr server on port 8983 (pid=94888). Happy searching!



Starting node2 on port 7574 using command:

solr start -cloud -s example/cloud/node2/solr -p 7574 -z localhost:9983   


Waiting to see Solr listening on port 7574 [|]  
Started Solr server on port 7574 (pid=94979). Happy searching!


Now let's create a new collection for indexing documents in your 2-node cluster.

Please provide a name for your new collection: [gettingstarted] 
gettingstarted
How many shards would you like to split gettingstarted into? [2] 
2
How many replicas per shard would you like to create? [2] 
2
Please choose a configuration for the gettingstarted collection, available options are:
basic_configs, data_driven_schema_configs, or sample_techproducts_configs [data_driven_schema_configs]

Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI
```

I am sure this used to work before.
But I am not able to figure out what's wrong.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ant server needs to be run to solve the classpath issue.

(Or ant example for older versions).